# php newline not getting detected in csv

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have this common issue of 'new line' in php-csv which is making me crazy!!! I checked so many forums and tried different workarounds, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. I'm reading from a CSV file which has 1 header and 2 data records. I skip the header using `fgets()` and reading the data records using `$data=fgetcsv()`. Now the problem is both the data records are read into single array. I tried the following options, but all in vain:

1. Runtime - `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);`
2. Turned auto_detect_line_endings to 'ON' in php.ini.
3. tried    `fwrite($handle, implode($delimiter,$fieldsarray).PHP_EOL);`

I'm working on MAMP in local, LAMP in dev region. The CSVs are saved on local machine, copied to /tmp/ folder and read from there. How can I check if there are necessary newlines in the files? When i check the file from tmp, I do see the records in new lines.

Comment: If it was line endings, then the first fgets would slurp the whole file - fgetcsv just adds the extra csv->array parsing after an internal fgets() call reads a line.

Comment: Seems like your newline issue propagated to SO also.

Comment: Can you post the lines in your csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution worked!!

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents($temp);
$file_cont_new = str_replace("\n","\r",$file_contents);
file_put_contents($temp,$file_cont_new);
```

Comment: Should that not be `str_replace("\r","\n",$file_contents);`

And if there are \r\n than you will get an empty line. So workaround would be
    `$file_cont_new = str_replace("\n\r","\n",$file_contents);
    $file_cont_new = str_replace("\n\r","\n",$file_contents);
    $file_cont_new = str_replace("\r","\n",$file_contents);`

Comment: @corban, there's an issue with that - the re-use of $file_contents.  The latter commands should use $file_cont_new.  Also, that could be simplified by dong the last one first, and then simply replacing all occurrences of ("\n\n"), using one less line.